# Azure AD: iOS client to Authenticate through .NET Core 2 Back End Web

Tags: ios, azure, .net-core

Currently, We have iOS application that connects to web backend developed using .Net Core 2 where it allows authorized users to download contents from the web and view through the iOS application. User management is happening through a local SQL database.

Now we have started to integrate Azure AD to our application and all web users were able to authenticate using Azure AD successfully. But our problem is how to enable Azure AD authentication to the iOS client. We found many samples in the Microsoft Azure site which explained how a Native app can directly communicate with Azure AD. But what we required is authentication to be done through our backend.

Can some please help us with this?

Comment: Can't you use Microsoft's ADALiOS framework and simply provide the token to your web service via a header?

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your suggestion. I followed through your suggestion and able to fulfill the requirement. For that, we implemented identityserver authorization endpoint at our backend web and iOS client communicated to the Azure AD through that endpoint. We used AuthAPI-iOS ObjectiveC library(https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) to do that. It is pretty good library with proper documentation and few good sample porjects

Comment: Glad. You got it working. You could also look at Microsoft's MSAL framework. It supports SSO and MFA via the Microsoft Authenticator app

Comment: @Paulw11. Thanks for your suggestion. I already checked the MSAL framework and it also worked fine. The reason behind the selection of AppAuth as ios library to support different OpenID providers like google. I had a doubt about MSAL library since it was designed by MS to support Azure. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it depends on what you want; If your target is only Microsoft enterprise environments, MSAL is the best approach.  I don't think it is a general-purpose OpenID/OAuth framework

Comment: For MSAL it clearly mentioned that it is designed for the Microsoft identity platform. Check here. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc#microsoft-authentication-library-for-ios-and-macos.